# Parse Push Notification delete invalid device token?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-cloud-code

Is there a way in code (Parse cloud code) for weekly check of inactive device tokens (users who installed and then deleted their apps) and delete them if necesary?

Comment: You could send a a special push notification to everyone and have the device check in within a set period of time after that. If it fails to check in, it's inactive. Keep in mind that, this way, you might lose devices that are offline for an extended period of time, i.e. because of vacations.